# MongoDB Default Write Concern not working

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a GO application which uses MongoDB database through a driver.

**Driver link**: [mongo driver](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2)

Recently I have created a replica set and got some error on subsequently dependent operations. To resolve this I have set Mongodb default write concerns using the below command on primary

```
db.adminCommand({
  "setDefaultRWConcern" : 1,
  "defaultWriteConcern" : {
    "w" : "majority",
    "j":true,
    "wtimeout" : 5000
  },
  writeConcern: {
    "w" : "majority",
    "j":true,
    "wtimeout" : 5000
  },
})
```

But it does not seem to be working because applications's second subsequent operation failed due to dependency upon preceding and hence falls in error.

In the application I am adding a document and immediately reading it to make sure and passing the values to another function. Once the document is added the find query is not getting any response hence further functions are not working.

To check this I have passed write concern manually in the first operation and it worked properly.

```
sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
defer sessionCopy.Close()
sessionCopy.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{WMode: "majority"})
getCollection := sessionCopy.DB(Database).C(coll)
err := getCollection.Insert(query)
```

If I remove `sessionCopy.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{WMode: "majority"})` the it does not work and find query does not find any document, can anyone explain why it is not working and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Why is what not working?

Comment: @D.SM the default write concern is not working. But when write concern is passed explicitly in the query then it works. SO my question is what am I missing here?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Add errors you are receiving or actual and expected behavior description.